# xray in blender 2.8

Tags: 3d-view

Most of the new features in blender 2.8 are very good, but, some features of 2.79 were better. In particular, the x-ray option was very good in the old .79 but, now the x-ray seems to be global, because, it makes the mesh also seethrough, and this gets pretty confusing while trying to put armatures in say hands, or doing retopo work.

[image]

I wonder if there is any other option or a work around to make only the selected object visible(x-rayed?), while not hindering the opacity of other objects in the scene.

Answer (score 3):

Under the overlay tab, check the "fade geometry" option as shown: 
[image]